# Is there some way to have y = k*m but in integers only?

Tags: c, plot, coordinates, equation

I'm trying to write out pixles on a LCD. I'm plotting them at X, Y coordinates and I'm using this code:

```
void SSD1306_draw_line(uint8_t x0, uint8_t x1, uint8_t y0, uint8_t y1){
    uint8_t k = (x1 - x0)/(y1 - y0);
    uint8_t y = y0;
    for(uint8_t x = x0; x < x1; x++){
        pixel(x, y, true);
        y += k;
    }
}
```

The problem where is that if k becomes a decimal number e.g 1.98, then k will still 1. If k = 2.01, then k = 2 due to the `uint8_t` datatype.

Assume that we are going to plot the line `(0,0), (40, 20)` {x,y}. 
Sure, now k will be 2. That works!

But assume that if we plot the line `(0,0), (35, 20)` {x,y}. 
Now k will be a float number of 1.75. This will not work for me. 
Is there a way to find a better k?

I have tried this, but the line does not follow the coordinates.

```
void SSD1306_draw_line(uint8_t x0, uint8_t x1, uint8_t y0, uint8_t y1){
    float k = 0;
    if(y1 > x1){
        k = (y1 - y0)/(x1 - x0);
    }else{
        k = (x1 - x0)/(y1 - y0);
    }
    float y = y0;
    for(uint8_t x = x0; x < x1; x++){
        pixel(x, (uint8_t) y, true);
        y += k;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may have changed `k` to a floating-point type, but all of the math you are doing to calculate its value is still integer-arithmetic.

Comment: Instead research [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for an all integer solution.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Wow! Thanks. I think that will be the answer  :)

Comment: There is also Bresenham's circle algorithm, integer only.

Comment: @WeatherVane I thought the original for curves was [Pitteway, M.L.V](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article-pdf/10/3/282/1333509/100282.pdf)

Comment: @DanielMårtensson There are subtle improvements to Bresenham's line algorithm, yet the [original article](https://web.archive.org/web/20080528040104/http://www.research.ibm.com/journal/sj/041/ibmsjIVRIC.pdf) is one of the most cited in computer graphics and worth the read, even just for its historical impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of attempting FP math, research [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for an all integer solution.

Untested code:

```
void SSD1306_draw_line(uint8_t x0, uint8_t x1, uint8_t y0, uint8_t y1) {
  int dx = x1 - x0;
  int dy = y1 - y0;
  int D = 2*dy - dx;
  int y = y0;

  // code still needs work when x0 > x1 or |dy| > |dx|
  for (int x = x0; x <= x1; x++) {
    pixel(x,y,true);
    if (D > 0) {
      y++;
      D = D - 2*dx;
    }
    D = D + 2*dy;
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try that. Give you a reply in 9 hours.

Comment: It works! Here is the result. Scroll down to SSD1306 OLED LCD: https://github.com/DanielMartensson/STM32-Libraries

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Your git code likely needs work in the case |dy| > |dx|.

Comment: But can't I just swap the values? 20 to 40 have the same distance as 40 to 20.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson |dy| > |dx| is not 20 to 40 vs 40 to 20.   it is (0, 0) to (40, 20) vs (0,0) to (20, 40).  When |dy| >|dx| code should use a `for (int y = y0; y <= y1; y++) {` loop (y vs x)

Comment: I will think about that! So I'm only need to replace the for loop head? Not the code inside?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Best to think about it for a while.  "need to replace the for loop head?" --> not quite.

Comment: Done! Have a look at the code now. Now it can handle all types of coordinates.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Consider [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you. I have tested the code in different coordinates and it seems to work great.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path with changing `k` and `y` to data type `float`.
But in addition to that, you need to make sure that the right hand side of

```
k = (y1 - y0)/(x1 - x0);
```

will be a float value, too. Currently, since only integral values are involved, the result of the expression on the right hand side will be integral. So `k` will never receive any fractional part.

To "enforce" floating point division, it is sufficient that one of the operands is of type `float`. You can achieve this by an explicit cast. Write, for example:

```
k = ((float)(y1 - y0))/(x1 - x0);
```